# JSON to Dictionary

Tags: c#

Am looking to convert a JSON string (as follows) to a dictionary.
[{'Key':'superuser','Value':'s'}]

Ideally, I would like to convert it a way that Dictionary[0] will be [superuser]=s.

But I end up having two elements in dictionary instead of one.
Could anyone guide me ?

Current Code

```
 JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string,string>>>(json)
```

Thanks

Comment: "But I end up having two elements in dictionary instead of one." That suggests you've already got code that you're trying. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Hi Jon, I have added current code.

Comment: Why are you deserializing it as a *list* of dictionaries? Surely it's effectively a list of key/value pairs, which you want to deserialize as a *single* dictionary.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CfBkVw

Comment: Jon, I had tried that. But since the Json is an array,I was running into 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array to Dictionary' errors.

Comment: Amit, thanks, but I needed it as Dictionary<string,string>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently deserializing it as a list of dictionaries, when you only actually want a single dictionary.

There may be a cleaner way of doing this, but you can deserialize it as a list of key-value pairs, then convert that into a dictionary. Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string json = "[{'Key':'x','Value':'y'},{'Key':'a','Value':'b'}]";

        var dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>(json)
            .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);

        Console.WriteLine(dictionary["x"]); // y
        Console.WriteLine(dictionary["a"]); // b
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. That did it.